# Notify on email sent - Postfix

Tags: arch-linux, email, postfix

I have a small postfix server, on a Linux server (Arch Linux) mainly used as a http server.

I use postfix to send database backups and notifications of my web sites. To avoid spamming, I'd like to monitor the output mail queue (e.g. a report of sent emails).

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Postfix logs that by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a cron job to run the [pflogsumm](http://linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html) postfix log analyser and send you a report.

If `pflogsumm` does not suit your requirements there are other alternative log analysis tools listed at http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#logfile